# How to Check which type of data type can a function takes in R

Tags: r

I know that `collapse::fmean` function can be applied to data.frames as well as a single vector. But is there any way to check the kind of data a function accept in R?

```r
collapse::fmean(mtcars)
#>        mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec 
#>  20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596562   3.217250  17.848750 
#>         vs         am       gear       carb 
#>   0.437500   0.406250   3.687500   2.812500
collapse::fmean(mtcars$mpg)
#> [1] 20.09062
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often R functions come with their own documentation. You can read it by using the command `?<function>`, so in your case `?collapse::fmean` (or equivalently `help(collapse::fmean)`).

For example this is how the help page for that function looks in RStudio:

[image]

As you can see in the last line, in this case it is clearly specified what kind of data is accepted for variable `x`.